# A problem on the chapter: Work, Power and Energy

Tags: calculus, physics

> **An engine of $150$ Kilowatt is drawing a train of total mass $1.5\times 10^5$ Kg up an incline of $1$ in $50$. The frictional resistance is $4$ Kg-wt per ton. Show that the maximum speed of the train is $4\frac{1}{6}$ meters per second.**

My attempt:

$150 KW=150\times 100$ W

If $\alpha$ is the inclination of the plane to the horizontal then $\sin{\alpha}=\frac{1}{50}$.
Component of weight of the train along the plane=$mg\sin{\alpha}=1.5\times 10^5\times g\times \frac{1}{50}=3000g$ N

Total resistance of the motion $=R=4\times\frac{1.5\times 10^5}{10^3}$ Kg-wt $=600$Kg-wt=$600g$ N (since $1$ ton=$10^3$ Kg)

If F be the force exerted by the train then $F=R+mg\sin{\alpha}=g(600+3000)=3600g$ N

The maximum speed is attained if the acceleration of the train is zero and force exerted by the engine is equal to resistance of the motion.

Let $v$ meter/sec be the required maximum speed of the train.

**Please check whether I am on right path and help me to complete the solution of the problem.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $150kW = 150 \times 1000W$. Not that it will make much of a difference, but instead of sine you should have $\tan\alpha = \frac{1}{50}$.

Comment: Just to explain my edit, please note that the (arithmetic-dynamics) tag is probably best used when referring to the subject described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_dynamics.

Comment: @Marconius: in this context the description of the incline refers to the valie of sine not tan

Comment: @DavidQuinn - I won't argue that, given that you are expected to take $g=10$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first make a free body diagram:

[image]

As you said, when the speed is maximum the acceleration is zero, and since the motion is only along the plane and never leaves it, we will be only dealing with the horizontal components:
$$\begin{align}
P_x+N_x+f_x+F_x&=0\\
-mg\sin(\alpha)-f+F&=0\\
F&=f+mg\sin(\alpha)\tag1
\end{align}$$

$F$ is constant, so let's recall the following formula between the power $P$ of the force $F$ and the work done by it:

$$\begin{align}
P&=\frac{\mathrm dW}{\mathrm dt}\\
P&=F\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\\
P&=Fv_\text{max}\tag2
\end{align}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get:

$$\begin{align}
P&=(f+mg\sin(\alpha))v_\text{max}\\
v_\text{max}&=\frac P{f+mg\sin(\alpha)}\\
&=\frac{150.10^3}{600\times10+1.5\cdot10^5\times10\times\frac1{50}}\\
&=4.1667=4\frac16
\end{align}$$

Comment: Would you explain what is the need of " speed is  maximum the acceleration is zero"?

Comment: Indeed, I'll give you a mathematical explanation. As you know $a=\frac { dv }{ dt } $ when the speed $v$ reaches its maximum its derivative will be zero as you learned in calculus(I can explain that too if you want) therefore the rate of change of velocity or its derivative with respect to time that is known as "acceleration" will be zero.

Comment: I know that speed is maximum implies acceleration is zero". I want to know why this is necessary for this problem? What is the need of this argument for solving the problem? Are we using "acceleration is zero" anywhere?

Comment: Oh, well to solve the problem we needed $F$ the force that drives the train(the one with the power 150Kw) , and to get that we solve for F as I did in the answer(sum of forces = mass*acceleration = 0(in this case))

Comment: OK i understand. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm glad to help ^^

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path. The driving force is $\frac{\text{Power}}{\text{speed}}=3600g$

Taking $g=10$, you get the expected answer.